# Upload a file with Chromedriver to a website that uses plupload.Uploader

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to upload a file to a website however the standard `SendKeys` method does not work because the website uses `plupload.Uploader()` to upload files.

Browse button:

```
<button type="button" id="media-browse-button" class="btn btn-primary" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">Browse...</button>
```

plupload:

```
var media_uploader = new plupload.Uploader({"runtimes":"html5","browse_button":"media-browse-button","container":"media-container","url":"\/upload","headers":{"Accept":"application\/json"},"chunk_size":"512kb","multipart_params":{},"filters":{"mime_types":[{"title":"Audio files","extensions":"mp3,m4a"}]}});media_uploader.init();document.getElementById('media-start-upload').onclick = function() {media_uploader.start();};
```

I have tried:

```
string MediaFilePath = "file path here"
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"media-browse-button\"]").SendKeys(MediaFilePath);
```

However this just opens a browse file dialog and does not upload anything.

Comment: Do you see this xpath in the webpage ? `//input[@type='file']`

Comment: I do not. The xpath I get is `//*[@id="media-browse-button"]`.

Comment: Unless it is this https://imgur.com/zW4MpYp

Comment: See below, using selenium do not perform click on upload button, directly send the keys like below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in entire webpage you have

```
//input[@type='file']
```

then `SendKeys` will `upload` the files.

```
string MediaFilePath = "file path here"
driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='file']").SendKeys(MediaFilePath);
```

Note that, you **should not click on upload button**, this would get the job done.